# Why cookie not set in request with corss-origin request

Tags: javascript, frontend

first i login by `https://examples.com` the backend api is `https://examples.com/api`, the cookie is correct set and sent.

when i start local web project in `http://localhost:3000` and send request to `https://examples.com/api` request is not cookie header.  the response cors header is already set

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-expose-headers: Date,Content-Encoding,Vary,Server,Transfer-Encoding,Connection
cache-control: no-store
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
```

why request header no cookie field ?

Comment: is there any relation between *CORS* and *cookies*?

Comment: the other answer tell me set property `credentials: 'include'` but not works.

Comment: can you show code for the request?

Comment: the response should have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header set to `true`

Comment: the response is already return `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` header

Comment: can you show request headers from devTools>network panel?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.

this because in 2020/08/11 the chrome update cookie secret policy

see also: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

we can set cookie property `SameSite=None;Secure=true` bypass https can be fix.